# neo4j complains about implicit grouping expressions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I copy one of the example class query from neo4j cypher aggregation class
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMTg0ujVjk

```
Match (a:Actor)
Where a.born is not null
And a.name starts with 'Tom'
with count(a) as NumActors, collect(duration.between(date(a.born), date())) as Ages
Unwind Ages AS x
Return sum(x), sum(x)/NumActors
```

However, in the neo4j web console provided by the class. I am getting this error

```
Aggregation column contains implicit grouping expressions. For example, in 'RETURN n.a, n.a + n.b + count(*)' the aggregation expression 'n.a + n.b + count(*)' includes the implicit grouping key 'n.b'. It may be possible to rewrite the query by extracting these grouping/aggregation expressions into a preceding WITH clause. Illegal expression(s): NumActors (line 6, column 8 (offset: 183))
"Return sum(x), sum(x)/NumActors"
        ^
```

Apparently, this query works

```
Match (a:Actor)
Where a.born is not null
And a.name starts with 'Tom'
with count(a) as NumActors, collect(duration.between(date(a.born), date())) as Ages
Unwind Ages AS x
Return sum(x)
```

So it was complaining when we sum(x) with NumActors as an implicit aggregation key. How can I achieve the same goal by updating the query (computing sum and average)? my initial query syntax looks perfectly fine to me...

Answer (score 0):

Use this function AVG() for this purpose:

```
Match (a:Actor)
Where a.born is not null
And a.name starts with 'Tom'
with  collect(duration.between(date(a.born), date())) as Ages
Unwind Ages AS x
Return sum(x), avg(x)
```

Sample result:

```
╒══════════╤═════════╕
│"sum(x)"  │"avg(x)" │
╞══════════╪═════════╡
│P276Y5M14D│P69Y1M11D│
└──────────┴─────────┘
```

reference:
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-avg-duration

For the explanation of your error, neo4j allows aggregation expressions if it follows some requirements stated on this guideline: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#grouping-keys

If you insist to use your original query, this is the fix as stated in the error message of neo4j. You should use WITH to get the sum() first then use it to compute the average.

```
Match (a:Actor)
Where a.born is not null
And a.name starts with 'Tom'
with count(a) as NumActors, collect(duration.between(date(a.born), date())) as Ages
UNWIND Ages as x
WITH sum(x) as total,  NumActors
RETURN total, total/NumActors as avg
```

Comment: After reading through the link you share, still not clear why NumActors cannot be the grouping key?

Comment: You cannot use aggregates (sum and count) with a different grouping keys. It is similar to SQL wherein you cannot use two group by. In your query, count() is using a while sum() is using duration of a.age.

Comment: Try putting your aggregations in a with statement and not the return. Also, the count and sum must be in the same line. You will need to use decimals (e.g., 12.0 or toFloat) to return a decimal result of divisions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky. So I will try to simplify it as much as possible. Let's try to understand how aggregations work, for this query:

```
Match (a:Actor)
Where a.born is not null
And a.name starts with 'Tom'
with count(a) as NumActors, collect(duration.between(date(a.born), date())) as Ages
Unwind Ages AS x
Return sum(x)
```

We first match for actors having their name starting as `Tom` and have some birth date. Let's say we have 10 actors, after the `MATCH` and `WHERE` clause executes. Now comes the statement

```
with count(a) as NumActors, collect(duration.between(date(a.born), date())) as Ages
```

This performs two aggregate operations, `count` and `collect`, but note that we have not specified any grouping key specifically. Hence the output, of this query will be a single row with two columns `NumActors` and `Ages`. Now we unwind the ages array, so now we will have 10 rows, and finally, we return the sum, since there is no explicit grouping key specified the sum is calculated for all the data rows. Hence it works.

Let's consider your query:

```
Match (a:Actor)
Where a.born is not null
And a.name starts with 'Tom'
with count(a) as NumActors, collect(duration.between(date(a.born), date())) as Ages
Unwind Ages AS x
Return sum(x), sum(x)/NumActors
```

Everything till `UNWIND` stage will be the same as above. Now, notice the return statement:

```
Return sum(x), sum(x)/NumActors
```

Here, also no explicit grouping key is specified. So, the `sum(x)`, will include all the rows, but the term `sum(x)/NumActors`, is erroneous because `Neo4j` is unable to determine, from which row the value of `NumActors` to pick up, since it is not specified as the grouping key. That's why you get the error. The message:

```
Aggregation column contains implicit grouping expressions. For example, in 'RETURN n.a, n.a + n.b + count(*)' the aggregation expression 'n.a + n.b + count(*)' includes the implicit grouping key 'n.b'. It may be possible to rewrite the query by extracting these grouping/aggregation expressions into a preceding WITH clause. Illegal expression(s): NumActors (line 6, column 8 (offset: 183))
"Return sum(x), sum(x)/NumActors"
```

Clearly says, that the key `n.b` is getting grouped, it can't be used in an aggregate expression. Similarly here, `NumActors` is getting grouped, we can't use it in aggregation expression. Try this:

```
Match (a:Actor)
Where a.born is not null
And a.name starts with 'Tom'
with count(a) as NumActors, collect(duration.between(date(a.born), date())) as Ages
Unwind Ages AS x
Return sum(x), sum(x)/COLLECT(DISTINCT NumActors)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that you used `NumActors` in the `RETURN` clause without making it an explicit grouping key.

#### OPTION 1

Specify `NumActors` as an explicit grouping key:

```
...
RETURN sum(x), sum(x)/NumActors, NumActors
```

#### OPTION 2

Don't do aggregation in the `RETURN` clause:

```
MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE a.born IS NOT NULL AND a.name STARTS WITH 'Tom'
WITH COUNT(a) AS numActors, SUM(duration.between(DATE(a.born), DATE())) as sumAges
RETURN sumAges, sumAges/numActors
```

NOTE: The code above also simplifies (and speeds up) the query by doing the `SUM` in the first (and now, only) `WITH` clause. You don't need the wasteful `COLLECT` -> `UNWIND` -> `SUM` sequence.

#### OPTION 3

If you don't need to have the sum of all the ages returned, just directly calculate the average age:

```
MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE a.born IS NOT NULL AND a.name STARTS WITH 'Tom'
RETURN AVG(duration.between(DATE(a.born), DATE())) as avgAge
```

#### ADDENDUM

There is another performance improvement that could be made to all the solutions, and it would also remove a possible error.

We should calculate the `DATE()` value once, put it in a variable, and use that variable to calculate all ages. Not only would it avoid repeated calls to `DATE()`, but it would guarantee that all ages are calculated using the same current date.

Without this tweak, then it is possible for us to use more than one current date during the calculation, which would give us an inconsistent result.

So, for instance, Option 3 could be turned into this:

```
WITH DATE() AS now
MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE a.born IS NOT NULL AND a.name STARTS WITH 'Tom'
RETURN AVG(duration.between(DATE(a.born), now)) as avgAge
```